# how to build a sorting key function in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, tuples

im now learning in online course and not struggling with this exercise:
ive got a list of tuples:

```
 [("candy","5.5"),("banana","2.3"),("chocolate","4.4")]
```

I need to build a function that sorts the tuple by prices. for that i need to build a key function i can put in `sorted()` and i dont get how it should be like.
ive tried this:

```
def choose_sec(my_list, new_list =[]):
  for i in my_list:
  new_list += i[1]
  for i in new_list:
    return int(i)
```

please help me

Comment: When writing questions, please leave personal information out and simply ask the question.  Don't need please help me or thank you or anything like that either.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort based on second element (its price) of every tuple like this:

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x: float(x[1]))
```

output:

```
[('banana', '2.3'), ('chocolate', '4.4'), ('candy', '5.5')]
```

If you don't want `lambda` expression you can do it with normal function:

```
def sort_with_price(input_tuple):
    return float(input_tuple[1])

print(sorted(a, key=sort_with_price))
```

learn more about sorting with `sorted()` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)